# I can't find button element with selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I add web element code with picture. How can i press this button with Java.
I tried like this;

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.className("_abm0")).click();
```

Or

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.className("._abl-._abm2")).click();
```

Or

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.className("_abl- _abm2")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working with;

Thread.sleep(1000); driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/button")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Are these classes unique for only 1 button element in the html page? Or are there others present on the same page?

a. If there is only 1 present, try the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='_abl- _abm2']")).click()
```

b. If there are more than 1 present you can try the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@class='_abl- _abm2'])[n]")).click()
```

--> n would be n'th button element --> 1,2...

Comment: I can't run it your code but it's working, just looks a little bad.

Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/button")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath -

```
//svg[@aria-label='New post']/parent::div/parent::div
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing difficulty in button click. then use the below xpath. that should solve the issue. the reason it wont work with using class attribute is that its a compound class so.

```
//button[@type='button']   
//*[@type='button']
```